# Mod Rewrite same format, different source

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Currently doing some URL rewriting for a company and I'm struggling to get the new URLs to point to the correct files.

I do not have access to the CMS - the pages are generated in two formats:

- website.com/pressReleases.php?lang=EN
- website.com/page.php?pagename=About&lang=EN

I have used rewriting for each format to make them into the same required format (website.com/language/pagename):

**Format 1 (website.com/pressReleases.php)**

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*).php$ /%1/$1? [L]
```

**Format 2 (website.com/page.php?pagename=About&lang=EN)**

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /page.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} pagename=([^&]+)&lang=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^page.php$ /%2/%1? [R=301,L]
```

The problem is that the output of the two format rewrites is the same, but the source files/path are different. When I create another redirect to forward the nice URLs to the actual source it applies to both:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ productSelection.php?    groupid=$2&lang=$1 [L]
```

Is there any way I can use the same nice format for both URL types, but forward to their original paths? Have I structured my rewrites incorrectly that is preventing this?

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to do a `-f` check first for the php file, then if that fails, use the 2nd format:

```
# format 1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%2.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/(.*)/?$ /$2.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]

# format 2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%2.php !-f
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/(.*)/?$ /page.php?pagename=$2&lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Also, you need to check against the actual request in your first format1 rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /([^\ \?\.]+)\.php\?lang=
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*).php$ /%1/$1? [L]
```